# How do i configure fiddler to show the parameters included in a url

Tags: fiddler

I am having problems with our .net openID authorisation

I am trying to use fiddler to view to flow of addresses and data, but fiddler isn't showing the url parameters in the return to localhost

so i tested this by typing

```
https://localhost:8080/#id=2
```

into IE and seeing what showed up in fiddler, it  was

```
1281    502 HTTP    Tunnel to   localhost:8080  512 no-cache, must-revalidate   text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:19884
```

i tried looking at fiddler help for configuration it suggested not using localhost but using your machine name, I tried this is wasn't any different.

Thank you in advance.

This is the pre-question to get all the information I will need for the next question about the openid problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be looking at the response of the line above for the information I needed. This question is closed thanks